# vue router next() function don't work in Promise in router.beforeEach

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following code:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name !== from.name) {
    store
      .dispatch("fetchCurrentUser")
      .then(() => {
        console.log('then');
        // do something
        next();
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('catch');
        router.push("/login");
        next();
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
  // next();
});
```

I'm trying to get the current user, and if this succeeds, then do something with this data, and if the request is not successful, then redirect the user to the login page. But next () calls do not work, I get the "then" or "catch" in the console, but the redirect does not occur and an infinite loop begins. But if I take next () from condition (commented row) the redirect works fine.

Comment: Do you have any other route guards in place? Does replacing `beforeEach` with `beforeResolve` change anything?

Comment: @raina77ow, no, beforeResolve behaves exactly the same

Comment: Can you provide code of your `fetchCurrentUser`? I think the error may be hiding here.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect you should use `next('/')` or `next({ path: '/' })`.

From the documentation:

> next: Function: this function must be called to resolve the hook. The
>   action depends on the arguments provided to next:
>
> next(): move on to the next hook in the pipeline. If no hooks are
>   left, the navigation is confirmed.
>
> next(false): abort the current navigation. If the browser URL was
>   changed (either manually by the user or via back button), it will be
>   reset to that of the from route.
>
> next('/') or next({ path: '/' }): redirect to a different location.
>   The current navigation will be aborted and a new one will be started.
>   You can pass any location object to next, which allows you to specify
>   options like replace: true, name: 'home' and any option used in
>   router-link's to prop or router.push

Comment: next("/login") also not called

Comment: Looking more carefully, I think that the promise is in wrong place to be called.
This example show how you may fetch data before enter in a route:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation

Comment: It is very strange, if in my project there are more than 200 components, I will have to register a handler in each

Answer (score 0):

The `promise` resolves after the function ends.

This means that the commented `next` happens regardless of the result of the promise result. Then the promise resolves and you call another `next`.

The bottom line is that you don't need the commented `next` and should just cover the promise resolve.

Comment: but I do not want to call next () until the moment when the promise is resolved. I want to get user data and find out his access level in order to understand where to redirect him further

Comment: I do understand that. You are calling next to many times. The last call is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried modify beforeEach function to async and await promise function finished. This work for me!

```js
router.beforeEach(async(to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.auth) {
    // need verification
    // This is a promise function 
    await widget.user
      .authVerification()
      .then(() => {
        next();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Session expired
        console.log(error);
        next("/login");
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to implement an async validation inside beforeEach, authentication in my case.

```js
export async function onBeforeEach(to, from, next) {
  let { someUserToken } = to.query
  if (someUserToken) {
    let nextRoute = await authenticate(to)
    next(nextRoute)
  } else {
    const userToken = store.state.application.userToken
    if (!to.meta.public && !userToken) {
      next({ name: 'Forbidden' })    
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
}

async function authenticate(to) {
  let { someUserToken, ...rest } = to.query

  return store
    .dispatch('application/authenticate', {
      someUserToken
    })
    .then(() => {
      return {
        name: 'Home',
        query: {
          ...rest
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return { name: 'Forbidden' }
    })
}
```

I hope this helps.